# Polling a raw Nexus Repository periodically from Java Code

Tags: java, nexus, sonatype

I have deployed a RAW Nexus Repository. Assume repo name as - `sampleRepo` and inside that the folder structure or group is like /test/files/. I have files inside /test/files folder. I need to poll this repo periodically using some REST API that Nexus offers. What are the APIs that can be used for this purpose? I thought of using the "**Search**" API. All I need to check for any addition or deletion of assets in this repo using Java. I am planning to maintain a DB for this purpose. Is my approach correct? Or anyone can suggest a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

I think the thing you are really looking for is [Sonatype Nexus REST Api](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/integrations/rest-and-integration-api). [There is a specific assets API](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/integrations/rest-and-integration-api/assets-api#AssetsAPI-Endpoints), that allows you to list artifacts in the specific repository. That seems to be what you want.